# Replace ControlTemplate with minimum code reproduction

Tags: wpf, combobox, styling, controltemplate

I wanted to modify the standard WPF `ComboBox` to also show an image on the left when `IsEditable` is set to `true`.

This is what I ended up with:

A `ResourceDictionary` in a separate XAML file with these contents:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">...</LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder">...</LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">...</Style>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">...</Style>
    <Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">...</Style>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">...</Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">...</ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">...</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and an include directive in the `Resources` property wherever I want to apply the new template:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="EditableComboBoxWithImage.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        ....
    </ResourceDictionary>
<StackPanel.Resources>
```

I only modified a tiny thing within `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">...</ControlTemplate>`

I understand that I cannot replace only a part of a `ControlTemplate`, so `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">...</ControlTemplate>` has to be fully reproduced.

Now my question is: is it possible to somehow get rid of the other contents of the `ResourceDictionary` by linking to them because they are part of standard WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can reference the original inner controls from the default `ComboBox ControlTemplate` in XAML, then unfortunately the answer is *No, you can't*... think about them being the `private` members of a class.

If you don't mind using code, then you can use the [`FindName` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `ControlTemplate` class to extract them, but really, it's more work than it's worth:

```
TextBox editableTextBox = (TextBox)controlWithDefaultControlTemplateApplied.Template.
    FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", controlWithDefaultControlTemplateApplied);
```

Comment: No, I was asking if it is somehow possible to only have `<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate">...</ControlTemplate>` in the ResourceDictionary (because that is the only element that I modified). The problem is that there are `{StaticResource}` references to the other resources which is why I also included them in the dictionary even though they are the WPF standard styles. (That's my question: can I change these StaticResource references so that they link to some standard WPF dictionary instead of having to reproduce them by myself)

Comment: In other words: what would be the best way to incorporate a modified "ComboBoxEditableTemplate" of a ComboBox in an application? Is this large ResourceDictionary that I produced above really necessary or is there a better way?

Comment: This is the page on MSDN for the default [`ComboBox ControlTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx).  When I need to define a new one, I copy and paste that into my local `Resources` section and simply edit it... eg. it is common to have large `Resource` files in a WPF Application that has custom controls in it. XAML is verbose and there's really not much that we can do about that.